# Switch from days to hours after a certain time

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Goal: Once the time hits two days or less, then it switches to hours instead of days.

Problem: In checking code by changing the date, it still only shows the days left, and not the hours. Am I missing something?

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 15, 2020 11:59:59").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    
    
 if (distance < 2) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("aep-countdown-date").innerHTML = hours + " hours left";
  } 
    
  else if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("aep-countdown-date").innerHTML = "The time has ended.";
  }
    
  else  {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("aep-countdown-date").innerHTML = days + " days left";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Date method [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns:

> the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch.

Your code `countDownDate - now` returns the number of milliseconds from now until the target date.

However, your comparison `distance < 2` is treating `distance` (which is in ms) as if it were in days.

You probably want

```
ms in seconds ------------------+
seconds in hour ---------+      |
hours in day ------+     |      |
         days -+   |     |      |
               |   |     |      |
if (distance < 2 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! That logic makes sense. However, I'm still getting 0 hours when I change the date to be less than two days out. I'm going to check to see if the hours variable needs to be updated in order to calculate the hours left.

Comment: So, that's a different question; you should create a new question on the site for that

Answer (score 0):

With help of the previous two responses, I figured it out. I added "2x" to the hours variable and changed the variable to days in the if statements and rid of the setInterval because it wasn't needed (I only need days and hours, not milliseconds and for it to constantly be firing):

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 15, 2020 11:59:59").getTime();

    $(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor(
            (2 * (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
        );

        document.getElementById("aep-countdown-date").innerHTML =
            days + " days left.";

        if (days < 0) {
            document.getElementById("aep-countdown-date").innerHTML = "Time has ended.";
        }

        if (days < 2) {
            document.getElementById("aep-countdown-date").innerHTML =
                hours + " hours left.";
        }
    });
```